# Disable spaceline on certain terminals

Tags: spacemacs, mode-line, spaceline

I'm using spacemacs for the convenience of largely not having to maintain my own emacs configuration, after 25 years of emacs use. For graphical frames and high-color unicode terminals, the fancy mode-line is fine.

However, I'm sometimes using a monochrome terminal, and the spacemacs mode-line is a lot worse on it than the traditional (emacs -Q) mode-line.

Is there a relatively simple way to toggle off the spacemacs mode-line for certain terminals?

Comment: Variable `window-system` is nil for a "character based terminal". To distinguish amongst terminal type, have a look at section 29.25 "Display feature testing" of the manual.  I don't know the details of mode line handling for spacemacs but I guess you could change the value of `mode-line-format` based on the found terminal characteristics..

Comment: Yes, this is the part I know how to do. The part I don't know how to do is to actually turn spaceline on and off. I suspect it is not enough to save and restore the values of mode-line-format.